# Applying a Typescript refactoring programmatically

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, automated-refactoring, typescript-compiler-api

VS Code has a `'Convert namespace import to named imports'` refactoring. As far as I understand, the refactoring is [defined in the Typescript codebase itself](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24469/files), so it's not specific to VS Code.

I need to run this refactoring on a source file programmatically within a Jest transformer. Unfortunately, I've been unable to find any documentation regarding running TypeScript refactorings programmatically. Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-refactor

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković that project seems to run some custom refactorings, but I need to run the refactoring already defined at the Typescript repo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TypeScript refactorings are supplied by the language server. VSCode uses the standalone [tsserver](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-%28tsserver%29) binary, but you can also use the API directly.

```ts
import ts from 'typescript'

const REFACTOR_NAME = 'Convert import'
const ACTION_NAME = 'Convert namespace import to named imports'

const compilerOptions: ts.CompilerOptions = {
  target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES2020,
  module: ts.ModuleKind.ES2020
  // ...
}

const formatOptions: ts.FormatCodeSettings = {
  insertSpaceAfterCommaDelimiter: true,
  insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces: false
  // ...
}

const preferences: ts.UserPreferences = {
  // This is helpful to find out why the refactor isn't working
  // provideRefactorNotApplicableReason: true
}

// An example with the 'filesystem' as an object
const files = {
  'index.ts': `
    // Both should be transformed
    import * as a from './a'
    import * as b from './b'

    a.c()
    a.d()
    b.e()
    b.f()
  `,
  'another.ts': `
    // Should be transformed
    import * as a from './a'
    // Should NOT be transformed
    import b from './b'

    a.a
  `,
  'unaffected.ts': `
    console.log(42)
  `
}

// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API#document-registry
// It was the only way I could find to get a SourceFile from the language
// service without having to parse the file again
const registry = ts.createDocumentRegistry()

// I think the getScriptVersion thing may be useful for incremental compilation,
// but I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible
const scriptVersion = '0'
const service = ts.createLanguageService(
  {
    getCurrentDirectory: () => '/',
    getCompilationSettings: () => compilerOptions,
    getScriptFileNames: () => Object.keys(files),
    getScriptVersion: _file => scriptVersion,
    // https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API#scriptsnapshot
    getScriptSnapshot: file =>
      file in files
        ? ts.ScriptSnapshot.fromString(files[file as keyof typeof files])
        : undefined,
    getDefaultLibFileName: ts.getDefaultLibFilePath
  },
  registry
)

const transformFile = (fileName: string, text: string): string => {
  // Get the AST of the file
  const sourceFile = registry.acquireDocument(
    fileName,
    compilerOptions,
    ts.ScriptSnapshot.fromString(text),
    scriptVersion
  )
  return (
    sourceFile.statements
      // Get the namespace import declarations
      .filter(
        node =>
          ts.isImportDeclaration(node) &&
          node.importClause?.namedBindings &&
          ts.isNamespaceImport(node.importClause.namedBindings)
      )
      // Get the refactors
      .flatMap(node => {
        // The range of the import declaration
        const range: ts.TextRange = {
          pos: node.getStart(sourceFile),
          end: node.getEnd()
        }
        // If preferences.provideRefactorNotApplicableReason is true,
        // each refactor will have a notApplicableReason property if it
        // isn't applicable (could be useful for debugging)
        const refactors = service.getApplicableRefactors(
          fileName,
          range,
          preferences
        )
        // Make sure the refactor is applicable (otherwise getEditsForRefactor
        // will throw an error)
        return refactors
          .find(({name}) => name === REFACTOR_NAME)
          ?.actions.some(({name}) => name === ACTION_NAME) ?? false
          ? // The actual part where you get the edits for the refactor
            service
              .getEditsForRefactor(
                fileName,
                formatOptions,
                range,
                REFACTOR_NAME,
                ACTION_NAME,
                preferences
              )
              ?.edits.flatMap(({textChanges}) => textChanges) ?? []
          : []
      })
      .sort((a, b) => a.span.start - b.span.start)
      // Apply the edits
      .reduce<[text: string, offset: number]>(
        ([text, offset], {span: {start, length}, newText}) => {
          // start: index (of original text) of text to replace
          // length: length of text to replace
          // newText: new text
          // Because newText.length does not necessarily === length, the second
          // element of the accumulator keeps track of the of offset
          const newStart = start + offset
          return [
            text.slice(0, newStart) + newText + text.slice(newStart + length),
            offset + newText.length - length
          ]
        },
        [text, 0]
      )[0]
  )
}

const newFiles = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(files).map(([fileName, text]) => [
    fileName,
    transformFile(fileName, text)
  ])
)

console.log(newFiles)
/*
{
  'index.ts': '\n' +
    '    // Both should be transformed\n' +
    "    import {c, d} from './a'\n" +
    "    import {e, f} from './b'\n" +
    '\n' +
    '    c()\n' +
    '    d()\n' +
    '    e()\n' +
    '    f()\n' +
    '  ',
  'another.ts': '\n' +
    '    // Should be transformed\n' +
    "    import {a as a_1} from './a'\n" +
    '    // Should NOT be transformed\n' +
    "    import b from './b'\n" +
    '\n' +
    '    a_1\n' +
    '  ',
  'unaffected.ts': '\n    console.log(42)\n  '
}
*/
```

There isn't much documentation on the TypeScript compiler API, unfortunately. The repository wiki seems to be the only official resource.

- [Using the Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)
- [Using the Language Service API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API)

In my experience the best way to figure out how to do something with the TS API is to just type `ts.` and search for an appropriately named function in the autocomplete suggestions, or to look at the source code of TypeScript and/or VSCode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extended answer! I'm going to play around with it. Do you have an idea though how it could be used within a Typescript AST transformer?

The problem is that I need this refactoring to be run within a `ts-jest` transformer: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/astTransformers/#public-transformers 

I'm just not sure how to convert the `newFiles` returned by your code into something that can be returned by a transformer.

Comment: In any case, I guess your response does answer my original question, so I'll accept it

Comment: BTW, this line of the output `index.ts` seems to be a bug related to char positioning:  `"import {e, f} from './b'./b'\n" +`

Comment: (ie, `'./b'./b'` shouldn't be duplicated)

Comment: @Maksym Oops, sorry about that! I added a `sort` before the `reduce` to sort the reactors by their position, and that fixed that issue. It's probably not the most efficient way to do it though.

Comment: I had a look at the ts-jest transformer thing and the `TsCompilerInstance` has an [internal property `_languageService`](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/aed734445c2c1e58cba191b8fa3858aaf931f08a/src/compiler/ts-compiler.ts#L72). I tried using that and then used `ts.createSourceFile` to create a new source file from the new text, but that didn't work because the new import specifier nodes didn't seem to have any symbols.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to copy [the code for the refactor](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3519af0bab9c8b7b4ca612da0cb7b5693f28713a/src/services/refactors/convertImport.ts#L85-L130) so you can directly transform the `sourceFile`. I'll have a look into if there's a better way to transform a `sourceFile` with the refactors from the language service.

Comment: Just a heads up: thanks to @cherryblossom I was able to create a workaround to a pretty annoying `jest-preset-angular` bug: https://github.com/Maximaximum/jest-namespace-imports-transformer